# ruby generate.rb load error

Tags: ruby

I am using phone gap and instal on window but when i am runing command it show please help me 
error:

D:\phone gap\phonegap-phonegap-android-0.9.4-38-g4008429\phonegap-phonegap-andro
id-4008429\bin>ruby ./droidgap C:\android\tools phonegap phonegap.pack D:\phone
gap\phonegap-phonegap-android-0.9.4-38-g4008429\phonegap-phonegap-android-400842
9\framework\assets\www" "C:\androidgap
:29:in `require': no such file to load --
D:/phone gap/phonegap-phonegap-android-0.9.4-38-g4008429/phonegap-phonegap-andro
id-4008429/bin/lib/generate.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
        from ./droidgap:4:in `'

error in this

:29:in `require': no such file to load --

Answer (score 0):

One quite important piece of information is: have you checked that path? As in d:/phone gap/.../generate.rb.

If it doesn't exist, do you have it somewhere else on your computer and can put it in that path? Does that work?

What that error tells you is that ruby can't find the file in that place.

Also, give more info. What OS (suppose windows) and any other useful info you can give. What have you tried yourself?